# Local defining function without constant rank implies not a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In a linear space, say $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, I know we can define embedded submanifolds with a locally defining function, which is equivalent to the canonical definition via diffeomorphisms. Following is the definition found in [An introduction to optimization on manifolds](https://www.nicolasboumal.net/book/IntroOptimManifolds_Boumal_2023.pdf)

> Definition 3.10. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a linear space of dimension d. A non-empty subset $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathcal{E}$ is a (smooth) embedded submanifold of $\mathcal{E}$ of dimension $n$ if either
>
> 1. $n=d$ and $\mathcal{M}$ is open in $\mathcal{E}$-we also call this an open submanifold; or
> 2. $n=d-k$ for some $k \geq 1$ and, for each $x \in \mathcal{M}$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathcal{E}$ and a smooth function $h: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ such that
>    (a) If $y$ is in $U$, then $h(y)=0$ if and only if $y \in \mathcal{M}$; and
>    (b) $\operatorname{rank} \mathrm{D} h(x)=k$.
>    Such a function $h$ is called a local defining function for $\mathcal{M}$ at $x$.

I wonder if we already have a locally defining function, in fact in my case, a globally defining function, but the rank of $Dh(x)$ is not the same in all $x$, does that basically rules out the possibility that the set I'm referring to is an embedded submanifolds?

I know some authors accept something like the disjoint union of two manifolds with different dimensions as a manifold, but I'm not sure that's relevant or useful in my case. For me, I need to consider a space in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and all points such that $\sum_{i}(p_{i}(x))^{2} = 0$, where $p_{i}(x):\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a quadratic function that does not use all entries in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I can technically break this globally defining function into multiple parts (since it is a sum of squares) such that it maps to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ for some $k$.

Sorry for not providing the exact details as this is related to my research, and I'm not working alone.

Comment: What is your question? It sounds like you're interested in a space 
$$
M = \bigsqcup_{i} M_i
$$ 
with disjoint components $M_i$, each of which is a manifold of dimension $d_i$. What is your question?

Comment: @SammyBlack So I think given a globally defining function, the "zero set" is always a disjoint union of smooth manifolds (in the definition above), essentially by partitioning based on the rank of the function. Is this true?

Comment: @SammyBlack My original question is that given a globally defining function, but the rank is not constant, can this set itself be a manifold (as in the definition above) of a single dimension?

Comment: Can it be? Yes. Must it be? No. The problem appears working over $\Bbb R$ in exactly your situation.

Comment: @TedShifrin It can? Can you elaborate, possibly with an example?

Comment: What is your definition of a "globally defining function?"

Comment: Consider the level sets of $X^2*Y^2$ that pass through the origin, for instance.

Comment: If $f=0$ defines a smooth manifold (i.e., $0$ is a regular value), then $f^2=0$ still defines the same subset, but every point is now a critical point.